# zpl extra label with garbage rectangle

Tags: label, thermal-printer, zpl

After this ZPL code:

```
^XA
^BY5,3,350
^FO140,80^BCR^FD11345678^FS
^XZ
```

The printer prints an extra label, with a black rectangle, as on photo.

[image]

Has anybody ideas what causes this? Is it a command issue or printer settings issue?

I tried to change the settings on the printer, but that didn't help.

Comment: It looks like a binary dump. No idea why this happens. How do you send the ZPL code to the printer?

Comment: Hi, it seems like the barcode is longer than the label. The barcode on the image is not scannable and when you insert this ZPL into labelary ZPL viewer ( https://labelary.com/viewer.html ) it displays way longer barcode. Maybe that is the binary dump.